# How to compute marginal hazard rate from parametric survival models?

Tags: survival, epidemiology, hazard, proportional-hazards, marginal-effect

Suppose that the conditional hazard rate for subject $i$ follows a proportional hazard model in the form of:

$h_i(t)=h_0(t) exp(\beta_1X_{i1}+\beta_2X_{i2}+\beta_3X_{i3})$

$X_i$ are subject-specific covariates. They follow known distributions (categorical or normal distribution). Suppose baseline hazard $h_0$ is constant over time. The subjects are censored at a fixed time by administrative censoring.
Is there an easy way to compute the marginal hazard rate in the overall population?

I was thinking about standardization/g-computation, but it does not seem easily applicable.